# Determining meters per second in scaled terrain

Tags: physics, mathematics, movement, terrain, scale

I have a terrain with a width of 199 and height of 99 and I'm scaling this train by 500. What would be 1 meter in the new terrain, would it be 500? I'm trying to move my character in meters per second and trying to figure out the correct speed amount to move him in meters per second.

I'm also trying to generate a random number for footballs, where the balls can be shot at you ranging from 30 m/s to 400 m/s but I'm quite confused on the measurements to determine m/s. I thought 500 would be correct for 1 meter in the new terrain but this would then mean I would need to generate a random value between 30*500 and 400 * 500 which seems to crash. Would appreciate any insight into this

Comment: Why are you scaling up this terrain in the first place? What are you trying to accomplish via this transformation?

Comment: Is this for a game or an accurate simulation? A football shot at 400m/s has a speed of 1440km/h (or ~900 mp/h). This is a bit too fast for most players to react and I do not want to be hit by that as well. 500 times that speed and you have a serious problem for anything between the ball and its destination.

Comment: @Zibelas I'm just doing random testing and trying to understand the measurement changes

Comment: "which seems to crash" what platform?